# Creating ramdisk with recent Raspberry OS causes "System has not been booted with systemd as init system..." error message

Tags: linux, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ramdisk

Quite a while ago I installed some Rasperry Pi 2 B+ with Raspbian and to reduce SD-Card usage I followed some instructions to create ramdisks.

For this purpose I added these lines to `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs size=10M,nodiratime,noatime,exec 0 0

none /var/run tmpfs size=50M,noatime 0 0
none /var/log tmpfs size=50M,noatime 0 0
```

That worked well at that time.

In the meantime I've also setup a Pi 3B+ with Raspberry OS but did not add that ramdisk.
After I noticed that and applied the same changes, I encountered strange behaviour.
I could not reboot any more:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

I could only restart via toggling power supply.
And even then I noticed that sometimes `/` was mounted readonly which wasn't fixed by toggling power again.

I can now reproduce the error by just installing a fresh image `2020-08-20-raspios-buster-arm64` or `2021-03-04-raspios-buster-armhf` (+`ssh` file in boot folder) and adding the lines to `/etc/fstab`.
Then I cannot use `sudo reboot` any more.

Are the options not valid any more in recent Raspberry OS? Is it generally not advisable to mount those folders to ramdisks?

When I execute `sudo mount -a` I do not get any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these entries to `fstab` interferes with Systemd.

`/var/run` is simply a symlink to `/run` on modern Debian. `/run`, in turn, already is a tmpfs. This `fstab` entry (or rather, its intent) is simply redundant, and has been for a very long time.

As for `/var/log`, this shouldn’t cause any issues. It might be a better idea to simply correctly set up what is writing there instead, so you can have persistent logs for critical errors without writing useless information.

If you want, you can also just remove rsyslog. You will still have the default in-memory journal that is accessible using `journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I really should update my setup a bit more frequently and not stick to old instructions